# How to pick a subset of values with const difference from a list of values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with list of values:

```
In [24]: data
Out[24]: 
[{'value': 1.2},
 {'value': 2.2},
 {'value': 1.8},
 {'value': 2.0},
 {'value': 1.1},
 {'value': 3.9},
 {'value': 0.0},
 {'value': 1.5},
 {'value': 2.5},
 {'value': 1.6},
 {'value': 2.3},
 {'value': 3.0},
 {'value': 3.3},
 {'value': 0.5},
 {'value': 4.0},
 {'value': 3.4},
 {'value': 0.8},
 {'value': 2.5},
 {'value': 2.1},
 {'value': 3.0}]

In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
    value
0     1.2
1     2.2
2     1.8
3     2.0
4     1.1
5     3.9
6     0.0
7     1.5
8     2.5
9     1.6
10    2.3
11    3.0
12    3.3
13    0.5
14    4.0
15    3.4
16    0.8
17    2.5
18    2.1
19    3.0
```

Now I want to pick a subset of this dataframe in the following way:

1. Pick max value - easy enough - `df['value'].max()`
2. Find the next N rows that have a value closest to the last value - 0.2

i.e. - max value is 4.0, so I want to find the row with value closest to `4.0 - 0.2 = 3.8`, i.e. row 5.
Next, I want to find a row with value `4.0 - (0.2 * 2) = 3.6`, so this would be row 15 (with 3.4), and so on (up to N times)

Is there a quick way to do that?

expected output:

```
value  
0 4.0
1 3.9
2 3.4
```

*The actual data I'll run with should be more evenly distributed, so around each expected value (i.e. around 3.8, 3.6, 3.4) there will be a number of close values (e.g 3.44, 3.38, 3.41)*

Comment: so your expected output should have just 3 values?

Comment: number of values is N - I want to control it

Comment: @CIsForCookies Considering the value close to `4.0 - (0.2 * 3) = 3.4` i guess the result would be `3.4`, Correct?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the resolution (`0.2`) is expected to be a lot larger than the distance to the closest, I believe you can use `merge_asof`:

```
step, N = 0.2, 3

maxval = df['value'].max()

(pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('value'),
                      pd.DataFrame({'ref':maxval-np.arange(N)*step}).sort_values('ref'),
                      left_on='value',
                      right_on='ref',
                      direction='nearest')
   .assign(dist=lambda x: x['ref'].sub(x['value']).abs())
   .sort_values('dist')
   .drop_duplicates('ref')
)
```

Output:

```
    value  ref  dist
19    4.0  4.0   0.0
18    3.9  3.8   0.1
17    3.4  3.6   0.2
```

Comment: Amazing! :) I'm sorry for not being clearer, but you got exactly what I needed. I just added a sort + dropna (in case N is too big) and that's it

Comment: There wouldn't be any `NaN` with `merge_asof` unless your data have them.

Comment: @ClsForCookies There's a slight difference in my solution and Shubham's. Mine wouldn't give the duplicated value as in Shubham's and only work with the assumption. It wouldn't work, for example, with the sample data and `N=4`...

Comment: This is fine - in the real data the assumption holds

Answer (score 3):

based on what I understood, you might want:

```
arr = df['value'].max() - (0.2 * np.arange(1,len(df)+1))
out = (pd.merge_asof(pd.Series(arr,name='Derived_value').sort_values(),
   df['value'].sort_values(),left_on='Derived_value',right_on='value'))
```

---

The above should do unless you want to sort exactly as per the values of the calculations:

```
out_one = (out.assign(Derived_value=pd.Categorical(out['Derived_value'],
        categories=arr,ordered=True)).sort_values("Derived_value"))
```

---

```
print(out_one)

   Derived_value  value
19           3.8    3.4
18           3.6    3.4
17           3.4    3.4
16           3.2    3.0
15           3.0    3.0
14           2.8    2.5
13           2.6    2.5
12           2.4    2.3
11           2.2    2.2
10           2.0    2.0
9            1.8    1.6
8            1.6    1.5
7            1.4    1.2
6            1.2    1.1
5            1.0    0.8
4            0.8    0.5
3            0.6    0.5
2            0.4    0.0
1            0.2    0.0
0            0.0    0.0
```

---

```
print(arr)
[3.8 3.6 3.4 3.2 3.  2.8 2.6 2.4 2.2 2.  1.8 1.6 1.4 1.2 1.  0.8 0.6 0.4
 0.2 0. ]
```

Comment: Hm, I'm thinking about `merge_asof` as well. But I think OP wants something else, `arr` would be `maxval-np.arange(N)*step`.

Comment: @QuangHoang yours is indeed closer (added `dropna()` in case `N` is too big), but I'm having trouble to explain what is exactly off

Comment: @CIsForCookies would have been better to have a better explaination:)

Comment: @anky I know :( I'm still thinking of how to put it in a concise and understandable way...

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing with numpy broadcasting:

```
N = 5
v = df['value'].max() - np.arange(N) * 0.2
dist = np.abs(v[:, None] - df['value'].values)

df['value'].iloc[np.argmin(dist, axis=1)]
```

---

```
14    4.0
5     3.9
15    3.4
15    3.4
12    3.3
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes! This is simpler when `N` is relatively small. But suffer from duplicated values...